# Google Gauge chart only throwing error in safari mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, google-visualization

listed below is my javascript code for a google gauge chart I am using in my application. This works in Safari, Firefox, IE and Chrome, but not Safari Mobile. When running, I get an error stating "Result of expression 'c[G]' [null] is not an object". This is an asp.net page with visual basic as the server side code - the <%= donevalue %> is a value from the server side which is the value of the gauge - changing this to any number still throws the same error.

note - The way I am viewing the site and getting this error is through http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/ - an adobe air ipad simulator.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>


    var percent = <%= donevalue  %>;
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['gauge'] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['%complete', percent]
    ]);

        var options = {
            width: 120, height: 100
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This error was only in simulator, works on actual device.